# Cannot Click Button after being Toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot Close the dropdown using the button but i can close it when I clicked the outer page.

[Working Demo here](https://codepen.io/OtakunityJL/pen/Edvxdj)

```js
var $menu = $('.menu');

$('.toggle').click(function () {
  $menu.toggle();
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
   if (!$menu.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
   && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
   {
     $menu.hide();
  }
 });
```

Please help me guys.

Comment: Your problem here is that the mouseup handler fires first, so you are hiding your menu when the mouse button is released on _any_ element on the page - including your button. The click handler for the button fires only after that - and so when the toggle method checks what the current state of the menu element is, it finds that it is hidden, so it gets toggled to be visible again.

Comment: If you modify your checks inside the mouseup handler to check if the `.dropdown` element or one of its descendants is the target, it should work. (Because then your button is included.)

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation();` @john see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $menu = $('.menu');

$('.toggle').click(function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
  $menu.toggle();
});
$('.container').click(function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
  $menu.toggle();
});
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  margin: 200px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.toggle, .dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
      <h1>jQuery: click outside to close menu</h1>
      <p>Click the button to toggle the dropodown menu.</p>
      <p>Then click outside dropdown menu to close.</p>
      <div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-default toggle">Toggle menu</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu menu">
    <li class="dropdown-item">List item 1</li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">List item 2</li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">List item 3</li>
</div>  
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Use `event.stopPropagation();` this will not prevent other handlers on the same element from running.

Comment: In CodePen You don't need to do that. It's not the point of the issue. He tried to bind two similar events for one object: `click` on `.toggle` and `mouseup` on whole `document` containing `.toggle` too.

Comment: @SumeshTG, U mean this snippet? Menu hiding won't ever work on button click. 'Cause there're two similar events with not-similar callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Simply U need only one action on mouse click. Your JS must be:

```
var $menu = $('.menu');
var $toggle = $('.toggle');

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  if ($toggle.is(e.target)) {
    $menu.toggle()
  } else {
    $menu.hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open and close on button. Just remove the second function and your code will work.

```
var $menu = $('.menu');

$('.toggle').click(function () {
  $menu.toggle();
});
```